# Induced EMF in our body

Tags: electromagnetism

I have learnt today that, Faraday And Henry independently found that In the changing magnetic flux, there will be Electric current in the conductor. Then why our body don't feel shock when we move magnet around our body.

My teacher told that that currents are very low, so we don't feel shock. But it doesn't makes sense to me, if we get a bigger magnet, I don't think that we feel Shock ? Why is it ? 

If my teacher is right, then tell me how and which is the minimum current that make us feel shock.

Answer (score 0):

When a straight line conductor of finite length say a conductor rod is moved in a magnetic field change in flux takes place that induces an e.m.f. across its ends & the current flow  will take place externally if the circuit is completed.

Although the [eddy currents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eddy_current) are induced within the conductor either it is a loop or a straight conductor & these are stronger especially for the thick conductors .

Our body can be treated as a straight conductor so if the magnet is big enough then our body can be affected by eddy-currents induced in form of loops within it even our body can be shocked.